# MySQL - COUNT, GROUP BY, ORDER BY and get latest Datetime

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a message table which I need to return the COUNT of messages, and the latest message that a specific user has sent or received.

The table looks like below:
[image]

The results I`m getting eg: for the user id 10 is:
[image]

BUT the result I want to have is:

[image]

I`m trying the following:

```
CREATE TABLE messages
(
    `id` INT, 
    `post_id` INT, 
    `post_user_id` INT, 
    `msg_user_id` INT, 
    `msg_from` INT, 
    `message` VARCHAR(55),
    `msg_date` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO messages VALUES (1, 100, 10, 15, 15, 'message 01', '2017-03-14 00:00:01');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (2, 100, 10, 15, 10, 'message 02', '2017-03-15 00:00:01');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (3, 100, 10, 15, 15, 'message 03', '2017-03-16 00:00:01');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (4, 200, 20, 10, 10, 'message 01', '2017-03-20 00:00:01');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (5, 200, 20, 10, 20, 'message 02', '2017-03-21 00:00:01');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (6, 200, 20, 10, 10, 'message 03', '2017-03-25 00:00:01');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (7, 300, 30, 10, 10, 'message 01', '2017-03-30 00:00:01');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (8, 300, 30, 10, 30, 'message 02', '2017-03-31 00:00:01');


SELECT *, COUNT(id) as 'counter'
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM messages
      WHERE post_user_id = 10 or msg_user_id = 10
      ORDER BY msg_date DESC) AS t
GROUP BY msg_user_id, post_id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

But I'm getting not the desired result, it gets the first message and date but I need the latest message and date.

Any ideas on that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for sharing this, I updated the question with more complete info, but somehow I could not make the SQLfiddle working... tks

Answer (score 0):

The desired output is not valid as there are different messages posted at different message date and the count can't be listed just on the basis of post_user_id and msg_user_id without ignoring other parameters. For Example: In 3rd row of result, desired count is 3, but all 3 records are unique and not sending 'Message3' only. Hence, the desired output is not valid.

However, You can use below specified query to get the message details using any specific condition i.e. It will print all the messages which have either post_user_id = 10 or msg_user_id = 10

```
SELECT *
      FROM messages
      WHERE post_user_id = 10 or msg_user_id = 10
      ORDER BY msg_date DESC
```

Now, In code you can figure out the the count and other desired outputs. OR you can fire a separate query for count.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it ins't what I'm looking for, I can select the grouped latest messages using the following, but can't think how can I get the COUNT of... `SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id)
             FROM messages
             WHERE post_user_id = 10 or msg_user_id = 10
             GROUP BY msg_user_id, post_id)
ORDER BY msg_date DESC`